# How to embed a custom content type in a Drupal 7 theme?

Tags: theming, nodes

How can I make a custom content type automatically available when a specific template is used?
e.g.: "Standard Page" is the custom content type I made with Drupal, going to structures-->content type etc. Now, it will be seen among the default content types, i.e. basic page and article. I want to make that custom content type, Standard Page, available without any effort when the template is enabled, i.e. without editing it: it must be embedded in the theme. How could it be done? 
p.s. I'm new to drupal theming. Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Comment: Answer: you can't embed content types in your theme, but you can save them and reuse them. Thank Boriana. Here's a helpful link on Feature module, that can do what I actually needed:http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct (answer below) -- you can't embed content types in your theme, however, you can create custom modules that users can install to have a content type you've created available.

If you are new to Drupal, and do not write your own modules yet, you can use the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module to create custom content types on your site, export them to a feature via the Features module, and import them to any number of sites.

Using the features module can be a little confusing at first, but there's lots of additional documentation and tutorials online.  I'd start with the module's documentation page first: http://drupal.org/node/580026.  :-)

Comment: Thank you Boriana, that would have been really helpful, if I had seen my profile yesterday. Actually, I found what you said, but googling for help: I installed Features, but maybe seeing your answer before searching all the evening I would have saved much more time. It seems to work perfectly :) very nice module!

Answer (score 0):

Content types and themes are completely different things, and you cannot simply embed a content type in a theme.